# How Do I Link My Whole Featured Article Image?

Tags: links, images

I'm using the Front Slider plugin to display featured articles on [my site](http://www.inkandpixelclub.com).  I've done some editing to the plugin to make it look the way I want.  Somewhere along the way, I must have missed changing a value, because the top half to the image for the article being displayed links to the article while the bottom half does not.

Assuming it's as simple as I think, all I need to know is what code I need to find and replace.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure where you put your own css but if it is inside the plugins folder then it might be wise to add it to a custom css file inside your them that way when an update comes out you dont have to re do all the editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the div#imglink is set to height: 150px; in your css. Change it to the same height as the images in the slider.